# an xpath that return a pair of values (using php)

Tags: php, xpath

I have lots and lots `paragraph` elements in XML and inside those paragraphs there are often child elements such as `name`. I want to run an xpath that will return the value of the child elements and the `xml:id` of the parent paragraph. The ideal result would be some kind of array where the key is the `paragraph` element's `xml:id` and the value is the text-node of the child `name` element. Any ideas how I could accomplish this with a single xpath?

Currently, I was trying something like that involved two xpaths and an attempt to put the two together, but this was getting pretty messy and not working.

```
    $result_array = array();
    $xmldoc = simplexml_load_file("$fullfilename");
    $xmldoc->registerXPathNamespace("tei", "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0");
    $names = $xmldoc->xpath("//name");
foreach ($names as $name)  
{
    $pids = $xmldoc->xpath("//tei:p[tei:name='$name']/@xml:id")
    $result_array[$name] = $pids[0]
}
```

I get an error here that says `[$name]` is an illegal offset. I also just don't think this will give what I want, because I believe its always going to return the `xml:id` for the first paragraph that has the child `name` element whose value matches the input. But what I want is paragraph xml:id value for the paragraph in which that instance was found.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you try https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/?

Comment: Please add your XMl to the question as well

Comment: Try changing `"//tei:p[tei:name='$name']/@xml:id"` to `"//tei:p[tei:name="+$name"+"]/@xml:id"`

Comment: have you tried casting the `$name` var like that: `$pids = $xmldoc->xpath("//tei:p[tei:name='".(string)$name."']/@xml:id")`?

Comment: You should also showw your XML otherwise I must admit it's not that much clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> SimpleXMLElement::xpath returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects or FALSE in case of an error.

Which means your using a SimpleXMLElement object as your array key, hence the error for illegal offset.

In order to get the real value to use it as key, cast it to string as follow:

```
$result_array[(string) $name] = $pids[0];
```